# Conflicting declarations in XC8 when using extern struct

Tags: c, embedded, pic18, mplab

I have a variable that is a struct, defined in a .c file:

```
struct {
    int write_cursor;
    int read_cursor;
    message messages[10];
} out_messages = {0, 0};
```

To make it available in other files I have an .h file with:

```
extern struct {
    int write_cursor;
    int read_cursor;
    message messages[10];
} out_messages;
```

This worked with the Microchip C18 compiler. The XC8 compiler gives an error:

```
communications.c:24: error: type redeclared
communications.c:24: error: conflicting declarations for variable "out_messages" (communications.h:50)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation isn't correct, you can do:

```
typedef struct {
    int write_cursor;
    int read_cursor;
    message messages[10];
} Struct_out_messages;

extern Struct_out_messages out_messages;
```

and in a .c make the initialization.

```
Struct_out_messages out_messages = {0, 0, {0}};
```

This compiles in XC16 without any problem, hope it does also on XC8.

Comment: Strangely, no (the latter). It gives me `communications.c:18: error: no identifier in declaration`. I wonder if I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the contents of the `struct` in multiple files, you could change the declaration in the header file to:

```
struct out_messages_t {
    int write_cursor;
    int read_cursor;
    message messages[10];
};

extern struct out_messages_t out_messages;
```

and then in your .c file, define and initialise:

```
struct out_messages_t out_messages = {0, 0};
```

(and include the header)